# Selenium: StaleElementReferenceException when element if used right after its found

Tags: python, selenium

I wrote selenium tests a few weeks ago and they worked fine when executed.

Now i get a `StaleElementReferenceException` exceptions in every test case. I did some research and this exception occurs when a DOM element is reverenced but it is deleted or no longer attached to the DOM ([docs](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp)). The thing is that i use it right after i search it.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("id_subject").clear()
```

If the element was not found then `NoSuchElementException` is raised and i immediately after the element is found reference it so why does it raise a `StaleElementReferenceException`?

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/somepath_to/tests/test_selenium.py", line 490, in test_donation_python
    driver.find_element_by_id("id_subject").clear()
  File "/somepath_to/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 73, in clear
    self._execute(Command.CLEAR_ELEMENT)
  File "/somepath_to/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 402, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/somepath_to/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 175, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/somepath_to/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=45.0.2421.0)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.15.322455 (ae8db840dac8d0c453355d3d922c91adfb61df8f),platform=Mac OS X 10.7.5 x86_64)
```

I have:

- implicitly_wait at 30 seconds
- the Chrome driver
- selenium version: 2.46.0

Comment: Could you provide the URL of the site? Actually, whatever last operation you are performing makes the DOM changes and so you need to reference the element again.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue in the past.

I was not using python, but the issue was caused by jquery refreshes to the page changing the DOM, and the elements were no longer valid. That might be the issue, even though there are other causes of such exception.

Comment: but can this happen if i search the element and immediately use it afterwards?

Comment: @yamm there is no such thing as immediately, you don't control how long it takes from executing a line of code to executing the next...

Answer (score 0):

BlunT has already given you the most likely scenario: you have a process that refreshes the DOM after `find_element_by_id("id_subject")` executes but before `.clear()` executes.

Since DOM refreshes are typically asynchronous, sometimes your Selenium code will work fine, sometimes it will fail.

I've fixed this problem using two general approaches in the past:

1. I've coded my Selenium test to wait until the refresh is done. This works well with code that I've written myself or if I'm using tools that are fairly well documented. An example of the latter is [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/). Upon performing an operation that refreshes the table, it is possible to wait until the table has refreshed before moving on.
2. For cases where I essentially cannot do the above, I retry until I do not get the exception. Something like:

   ```
   while True:
       try:
           driver.find_element_by_id("id_subject").clear()
           break # We're done!
       except StaleElementReferenceException:
           pass # Continue looping.
   ```

   This works only if it does *not* matter whether you perform your `clear()` operation *before* the DOM refresh or *after*. If it *does* matter, then you cannot use this method.